# OpenSuse won't boot without my pendrive plugged in

Tags: linux, boot, usb-storage, opensuse

I was building LFS on a pendrive this morning when it crashed in the middle of making gcc. I rebooted without my pendrive and I never got into the desktop. Instead, I get a visually pleasing terminal telling me that it couldn't find  and that the only way to reboot would be to press CTRL+D. I'm then given a command line and that's that.

Rebooting with the key inside works perfectly.

I reformatted my key and now there's nothing on it. I feel like somewhere somehow I added an entry to the boot process of my system and now I have to remove it. Never dealt with something like this before so any help is appreciated.

Fstab:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD2500AAJS-60Z0A0_WD-WCAV2M336077-part1 swap                 swap       defaults              0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD2500AAJS-60Z0A0_WD-WCAV2M336077-part2 /                    ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 1
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD2500AAJS-60Z0A0_WD-WCAV2M336077-part3 /home                ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 2
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD10EALS-00Z8A0_WD-WCATR0242669-part1 /windows/C           ntfs-3g    users,gid=users,fmask=133,dmask=022,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0
proc                 /proc                proc       defaults              0 0
sysfs                /sys                 sysfs      noauto                0 0
debugfs              /sys/kernel/debug    debugfs    noauto                0 0
devpts               /dev/pts             devpts     mode=0620,gid=5       0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-LaCie_iamaKey_10010805fd235c-0:0-part1 /mnt/lfs             ext4       acl,user_xattr        1 2
```

The LaCie entry at the bottom there is my pendrive. Any suggestions on fixing this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your system can't find the device the root filesystem lives on.  This can be set either via a kernel command-line parameter, which is what rescue disks do, or more commonly, and more likely in this case, the `/etc/fstab` file.  That's the file that you might have modified.

Comment: I added in a copy of my fstab file. Any ideas?